# Viewing raw RSS feed?

Tags: xml, wordpress, rss

I use WordPress for several websites.  I want to customize one of the RSS feeds and create a template for the outputted data but everytime I click on the feed link (myurl.com/feed) it takes me to a Google page to add it to my Google Reader.  I use Google Reader and normally want everything else to default to that, but how can I override it this one time so I can see the raw xml/rss feed?  Thanks.

Comment: This is not a programming question. It's trouble with browser settings.

Comment: Well since I'm trying to customize my Wordpress RSS template, I figured there'd be some kind of plugin or php code I could use.  Or someone would know how to override Google's default setting.  Thanks! :)

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I've tried Chrome, Firefox and Safari. I'm on a Mac. All of those have some sort of alternative formatting for rss feeds. None of them will show the feed as it is. If it's trouble with a browser setting, then does anyone know what that setting is to fix it? I've tried using Chrome's "view-source: feed.com/url" but it did not work either. I hate these readers and I never want them to show up on my computer, but I cannot find an option to turn it off.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

I used a combination of several different browsers to test how each RSS feed was displayed, then I customized my stylesheet based on the output.

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what you did?

Comment: This answer doesn't really relate to the question.  He's asking how to disable Google feed reader.

Answer (score 7):

The best way to view raw RSS is with CURL over the command line. Browsers can alter the source (firefox in particular) when showing it to you so the best thing is to get it unfiltered from curl.

Comment: Would have made sense to write a line as example.

Answer (score 3):

### A solution that doesn't require using different browsers:

In Firefox preferences, select Applications and search for "Web Feeds."  Changing the action to "Preview in Firefox" allows Firefox to load the feed itself, instead of google reader.  It has a "gussied up" display of the feed in the browser, but you can also view the source to see the actual text of the feed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a difference broswer, though most browsers will apply an xsl stylesheet to raw feed data by detecting that its a feed using the http response content type header. I know that Google Chrome shows some kind of raw data for rss feeds though its not exactly pure xml.

You can Use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to see the response. Or use some other http sniffer tool.

Answer (score 0):

Change the browser settings for your feed initially - you can change it back afterwards.  Once done...

View the RSS feed, it will show you a pretty version.  Then view the source code. You'll see the raw feed.  No different browsers, no CURL, no WGET.