# View Well-Formatted Raw RSS Feed in Browser

Tags: xml, rss, xml-parsing

Got a partial answer from searching in this thread: [Viewing raw RSS feed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364336/viewing-raw-rss-feed)

But I tried some of their suggestions and had no luck.  I use Chrome most of the time, and all I want is to be able to view a raw RSS feed in the browser that is well formatted and easy to read, so I can do some parsing for a project I'm working on.  As it is now I see the feed but it's essentially one enormous block of text with no line breaks, spacing, or highlighting.

One solution appears to be Curl, but honestly when I tried to install it, it was a little over my head.  If someone could point me to a Curl tutorial that would make it clear to me what the heck to do with it I would appreciate that.  I did find a partial solution, which was XmlSHell (http://www.softgauge.com/xmlshell/index.htm), but it's not ideal since it's not in-browser.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You could check out some of the Chrome extensions -- I think there's a couple now that give you good XML views. I think XMLTree gets mentioned a fair bit (see [this Super User answer](http://superuser.com/questions/972/displaying-xml-in-the-chrome-browser)), but I can't try it out now, as I'm at (IE-only, damn it) work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you view the source, you should get the XML in a bit more readable way.

If you use Firefox or IE, they will detect RSS feed and format it in a much more friendly way.

The reason why Chrome doesn't has to do with XML and standards for display. Technically, if you want any XML document to display with formatting, you have to attach an XSLT transformation to direct how the XML should be displayed.

Comment: I tried viewing the source but didn't make a difference.  Could I be missing something? I'm trying to view the RSS feed from a Picasa album: https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/base/user/110549449985131962981/albumid/5110936439138632625?alt=rss&kind=photo&authkey=Gv1sRgCK-ww-SBx7y6WQ&hl=en_US

Comment: The source doesn't help, because they don't have any formatting in the source either unfortunately.

Answer (score 7):

I wrote a web app that displays feeds in unobscured XML.

http://xmlviewer.scripting.com/?url=http://static.scripting.com/myReallySimple/linkblog.xml

Then I link to the app instead of linking to the feed.

It's really unfortunate how the browser vendors have interfered with the proper functioning of RSS.

Comment: Very cool idea, but it still won't format it. Still displayed as a single line.  I'm trying to get the RSS feed from a Picasa user.

http://xmlviewer.scripting.com/?url=https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/base/user/110549449985131962981

Comment: Aha! You're right. I just added a feature to my xmlviewer app that accounts for this. If you're sure it's a well-formed XML document, add a "compile=1" parameter to the URL and it first parses the XML, then serializes it in a uniform way. Now, no matter what weird obfuscation techniques they use, you'll be able to read it without going blind.

Comment: http://xmlviewer.scripting.com/?compile=1&url=https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/base/user/110549449985131962981

Answer (score 0):

Just right click on the page, download the file, and save it to your local drive, then view it in your dev software.

Should work fine.

Comment: Yeah that's my current solution but I was hoping to be able to view it in browser.